# Update Path Automatically at date change ?

Tags: c#

my program is watching a text file log - generated each day automatically.

now when the day change my program keep using the last day file path,

is there a way to do so without checking that the datetime.day each time and equal it to the day when the app launched at?

i saw SystemsEvent.TimeChanged but it only work when the user change the date manualy,

thanks.

Comment: Use a file system watcher over the parent folder and look for the file new file event.

Comment: You need to give more context explaining what you really did and ideally some code sample so someone can understand your problem.

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear, but have you looked at [`DateTime.Now`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx)?

Comment: why don't you want to check the date with `DateTime`?

Comment: Even if you are going to check current datetime every second, it won't kill your performance. So what's the problem here? Please be specific.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to do this is make your path using a `DateTime` object. For example;

```
   string fp = @".\subdir\otherSubdir\somefile-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + ".log";
```

Of course I don't know what the format of your date is. Docs on format specifiers for DateTime's ToString method can be found here; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

As pointed out in the comments you could also use a `FileSystemWatcher` however, that is quite a bit more complicated and likely unnecessary here. If you're looking for a more general solution (something that could work with files that use different naming conventions) that would be the way to go.

Comment: i am using that kind of path but when the day is changing the path is still the last time, thats why i asked if there is anyway keeping the path out of the loop, thanks.

Comment: @Dan272 what you're saying makes no sense. What loop is this path in? Today `DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");` returns 5-3-2013 tomorrow it retuns 5-4-2013. `fp` will be different tomorrow than it is today. The only reason it wouldn't is you're application is running as a service and the code setting the path is only executed at start up. Make sure `fp` is set each time before you try to read the file.

Comment: thats exactly what i mean, the path atm is only runing at the start up, my question was if there is any trigger that will alerm me when the day is changed or i need to check the path date at each loop (when read the file), becouse the file is beeing read every 100ms, and if the application will have delay creating the new log file and my APP will try read the next day file - it will crash my app. thats why i wanted to know is there is a trigger - thanks agian.

Comment: @Dan272 the `FileSystemWatcher` could be used to make your program event driven; ie when a change occurs within the dir you're watching you can open the file. Otherwise, you could just set the path in the loop and use `File.Exists(fp)` or a try-catch to prevent your application from crashing. The example here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx shows how to set up the FSW, it's pretty simple.